# Special treatment for last element in \@for

Tags: loops

I'm trying to make a macro such that I give it arguments like this

```tex
\sqrtnorm{x,y,z}
```

such that it expands to,

```tex
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
```

I'm trying (for no special reason) doing this with `\@for` command, this is what I've attempted

```tex
   \makeatletter
    \newcommand\sqrtnorm[1]{
        \sqrt{
    \@for\levar:=#1\do{
        {\levar}^2+}
        }
    }
    \makeatother
```

It's perfect in every way, except that there is a little + hanging around at the end. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Also, yeah, I kinda solved it now, by inverting the position of the + and just treating the first case as special. But maybe there is still a way to solve it by really considering the last case scenario?

Answer (score 2):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sqrtnorm}{m}
 {
  % make a sequence from the argument
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  % add ^2 to every item
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { ##1^2 }
  % deliver the sequence with + between items
  \sqrt{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { + }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\sqrtnorm{x,y,z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]